# this code give this exception "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.' "

Tags: c#, .net

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace FileManager
{
    class FileManager : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly string filePath;         
        private readonly string copiedFilePath;
        //private readonly Stream openFile;
        private readonly StreamReader streamReader;
        private readonly StreamWriter streamWriter;
        private readonly StreamWriter streamCopy;
        private readonly bool boolAppend = true;


        public FileManager(string filePath, string destinationPath)
        {
            this.filePath = filePath;
            this.copiedFilePath = destinationPath;
            if (!File.Exists(filePath) || !File.Exists(destinationPath))
            {
                throw new Exception("file not found");
            }
            this.streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.filePath,boolAppend);
            this.streamReader = new StreamReader(this.filePath);
            this.streamCopy = new StreamWriter(this.copiedFilePath, boolAppend);
        }
        public string ReadFromFile()
        {
            string content = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            return content;
        }
        public void WriteToFile(string content)
        {
             streamWriter.WriteLine(content);
        }
        public void Copy()
        {
            string copiedcontent = ReadFromFile();
            streamCopy.WriteLine(copiedcontent);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            streamCopy.Dispose();
            streamReader.Dispose();
            streamWriter.Dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

I'm trying to make an example on how to implement Idisposable interface to my FileManager calss.
is there any way to dispose streamCopy , streamReader and streamWriter in the dispose() method without getting this error?

thanks in advance for your help
.

Comment: There's no way this would be thrown on Dispose. Post the actual full exception text. Not just the message, the *full text* including the call stack. This will show where the error is actually thrown. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()` or by clicking on `Copy Details` in the exception popup while debugging

Comment: Apart from that, you don't StreamReader, StreamWriter. You can use `Stream.CopyTo(Stream)` to copy from one screen to another

Comment: this error is thrown in the contructor

Comment: Because you open the same file twice

Comment: in the main the instance is in a using(){} @TheGeneral

Comment: @someone doesn't matter - you're trying to open the same file twice. Once for reading, once for writing. Why are you doing this? You can't read and write at the same time. Even if you used a single stream, you wouldn't be able to use read after write or vice versa without changing the stream's position

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? Whatever it is, it should be done differently. It's quite likely the class isn't needed at all. `WriteToFile` does what `File.AppendLine` does. `ReadfFromFile` does the same as `File.ReadAllText`.

Comment: I'm trying to make an example on how to implement Idisposable interface to a class.@PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

Do you really get the exception during Dispose? I would guess the error is in the constructor. These two lines open the same file twice:

```
this.streamWriter = new StreamWriter(this.filePath,boolAppend);
this.streamReader = new StreamReader(this.filePath);
```

The second line probably causes the exception, because the file is already open.

Comment: yes the second line is causing the exception,any idea on how to resolve it.
Thank you.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're actually trying to do. Do you want to copy the file or read it? If you want a stream for read-write access to the file, use a FileStream instead of a StreamWriter/StreamReader.